# Well-Structure Bootstrap Login form in Razor view page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor, glyphicons

I'm trying to structure correctly my Login form which is designed in Bootstrap.
It's a Simple one but I can't still get it right.

What I want is the outcome must be similar to the following:
[image]

But Actually I have this one:
[image]

I would like to my Login form to be similar to the first Login Picture.

Here is my Login Form:

```
<body class="hold-transition login-page">
    <div class="login-box">
        @*<div class="login-logo">
            <a href="#"><b>TMS</b></a>
        </div>*@
        <!-- /.login-logo -->
        <div class="login-box-body">
            <p class="login-box-msg">Sign in to start your session</p>

            <section id="loginForm" class="left col-md-8">
                <h2>Use a local account to log in.</h2>
                <form method="post">
                    @AntiForgery.GetHtml()
                    @* If one or more validation errors exist, show an error *@
                    @Html.ValidationSummary("Log in was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.", excludeFieldErrors: true, htmlAttributes: null)
                    <div style="color:#000;" class="btn btn-info col-lg-offset-3">
                        <img src="~/Icon/icons8-high-priority-40.png" width="21" height="19" />  @Page.LogMessage
                    </div>
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Log in to Your Account</legend>

                        <div class="form-horizontal">
                            <div class="email form-group has-feedback">
                                <label for="email" @if (!ModelState.IsValidField("email")) { <text> class="error-label control-label col-md-4" </text> }>Email address</label>
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class = "form-control" value="@email" @Validation.For("email") />
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span>
                                    @* Write any user name validation errors to the page *@
                                    @Html.ValidationMessage("email")

                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="password form-group has-feedback">
                                <label for="password" @if (!ModelState.IsValidField("password")) { <text> class="error-label control-label col-md-4" </text> }>Password</label>
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    <input type="password" id="password" class = "form-control" name="password" @Validation.For("password") />
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
                                    @* Write any password validation errors to the page *@
                                    @Html.ValidationMessage("password")

                                </div>

                            </div>
                              <div class="remember-me row">
                                <div class="col-xs-8">
                                    <div class="checkbox icheck">
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="rememberMe" name="rememberMe" value="true" checked="@rememberMe" />
                                        <label class="checkbox" for="rememberMe">Remember me?</label>
                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                              </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-offset-8 col-md-4">
                              <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat" />
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                        </div><br />

                        @*<div style="color:#f00; width:220px" class="message-infolog">
                            <span style="initial-letter-wrap:initial; text-decoration-line:underline;"><img src="~/Icon/icons8-high-priority-40.png" width="21" height="19" /> @Page.LogMessage</span>
                        </div>*@
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
                @*<p>
            <a href="~/Account/Register">Don't have a Account?</a>
            <a href="~/Account/ForgotPassword">Did you forget your password?</a>
        </p>*@
            </section>
            <div class="social-auth-links text-center">
                <p>- OR -</p>
                <button class="lead btn btn-success">
                    <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-2x fa-fw"></i>
                    <a href="@Href("~Account/SignIn.cshtml")" id = "loginHome" class = "btn btn-block btn-social btn-facebook btn-flat" >                        
                        <span class="sr-only">Sign in using</span><b style="color:#000">365</b>
                    </a>
                </button>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>


</body>
```

**HTML Header:**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>@Page.Title</title>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Scripts/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Scripts/bower_components/Ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Scripts/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Scripts/plugins/iCheck/square/blue.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic">
</head>
```

**CSS**

```
html {
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-top: solid 10px #000;
    color: #333;
    font-size: .85em;
    font-family: "Segoe UI", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/*a {
    color: #333;
    outline: none;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-right: 3px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

    a:link, a:visited,
    a:active, a:hover {
        color: #333;
    }

    a:hover {
        background-color: #c7d1d6;
    }

header, footer, hgroup,
nav, section {
    display: block;
}*/

mark {
    background-color: #a6dbed;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

.float-left {
    float: left;
}

.float-right {
    float: right;
}

.clear-fix:after {
    content: ".";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

h1, h2, h3,
h4, h5, h6 {
    color: #000;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 1.75em;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

h5, h6 {
    font-size: 1em;
}

    h5 a:link, h5 a:visited, h5 a:active {
        padding: 0;
        text-decoration: none;
    }


/* main layout
----------------------------------------------------------*/
.content-wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 960px;
}

#body {
    background-color: #efeeef;
    clear: both;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
}

    .main-content {
        background: url("../Images/accent.png") no-repeat;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-top: 30px;
    }

    .featured + .main-content {
        background: url("../Images/heroAccent.png") no-repeat;
    }

header .content-wrapper {
    padding-top: 20px; 
}

footer {
    clear: both;
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
    font-size: .8em;
    height: 100px;
}


/* site title
----------------------------------------------------------*/
.site-title {
    color: #c8c8c8;
    font-family: Rockwell, Consolas, "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 2.3em;
    margin: 0;
}

.site-title a, .site-title a:hover, .site-title a:active {
    background: none;
    color: #c8c8c8;
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}


/* login
----------------------------------------------------------*/
#login {
    display: block;
    font-size: .85em;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    text-align: right;
}

    #login a {
        background-color: #d3dce0;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-right: 3px;
        padding: 2px 3px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    #login a.email {
        background: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    #login ul {
        margin: 0;
    }

    #login li {
        display: inline;
        list-style: none;
    }


/* menu
----------------------------------------------------------*/
ul#menu {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: right;
}

    ul#menu li {
        display: inline;
        list-style: none;
        padding-left: 15px;
    }

        ul#menu li a {
            background: none;
            color: #999;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        ul#menu li a:hover {
            color: #333;
            text-decoration: none;
        }


/* page elements
----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* featured */
.featured {
    background-color: #fff;
}

    .featured .content-wrapper {
        background-color: #7ac0da;
        background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #7ac0da 0%, #a4d4e6 100%);
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #7ac0da 0%, #a4d4e6 100%);
        background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, #7ac0da), color-stop(1, #a4d4e6));
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #7ac0da 0%, #a4d4e6 100%);
        background-image: linear-gradient(left, #7ac0da 0%, #a4d4e6 100%);
        color: #3e5667;
        padding: 20px 40px 30px 40px;
    }

        .featured hgroup.title h1, .featured hgroup.title h2 {
            color: #fff;
        }

        .featured p {
            font-size: 1.1em;
        }

/* page titles */
hgroup.title {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

hgroup.title h1, hgroup.title h2 {
    display: inline;
}

hgroup.title h2 {
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-left: 3px;
}

/* features */
section.feature {
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
}

/* ordered list */
ol.round {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}

    ol.round li {
        margin: 25px 0;
        padding-left: 45px;
    }

        ol.round li.zero {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList0.png") no-repeat;
        }

        ol.round li.one {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList1.png") no-repeat;
        }

        ol.round li.two {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList2.png") no-repeat;
        }

        ol.round li.three {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList3.png") no-repeat;
        }

        ol.round li.four {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList4.png") no-repeat;
        }

        ol.round li.five {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList5.png") no-repeat;
        }

        ol.round li.six {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList6.png") no-repeat;
        }

        ol.round li.seven {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList7.png") no-repeat;
        }

        ol.round li.eight {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList8.png") no-repeat;
        }

        ol.round li.nine {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList9.png") no-repeat;
        }

/* content */
article {
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
}

aside {
    float: right;
    width: 25%;
}

    aside ul {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
    }

        aside ul li {
            background: url("../Images/bullet.png") no-repeat 0 50%;
            padding: 2px 0 2px 20px;
        }

.label {
    font-weight: 700;
}

/* login page */
/*#loginForm {
    border-right: solid 2px #c8c8c8;
    float: left;
    width: 55%;
}

    #loginForm .validation-error {
        display: block;
        margin-left: 15px;
    }

    #loginForm .validation-summary-errors ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #loginForm .validation-summary-errors li {
        display: inline;
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
    }

    #loginForm input {
        width: 250px;
    }

    #loginForm input[type="checkbox"],
    #loginForm input[type="submit"],
    #loginForm input[type="button"],
    #loginForm button {
        width: auto;
    }*/

#socialLoginForm {
    margin-left: 40px;
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
}

    #socialLoginForm h2 {
        margin-bottom:  5px;
    }

#socialLoginList button {
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#logoutForm {
    display: inline;
}

/* contact */
.contact h3 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.contact p {
    margin: 5px 0 0 10px;
}

.contact iframe {
    border: 1px solid #333;
    margin: 5px 0 0 10px;
}

/* forms */
fieldset {
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

    fieldset legend {
        display: none;
    }

    fieldset ol {
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
    }

        fieldset ol li {
            padding-bottom: 5px;
        }

label {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 600;
}

label.checkbox {
    display: inline;
}

input, textarea {
    border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
    background: #fff;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin: 5px 0 6px 0;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 300px;
}

textarea {
    font-family: inherit;
    width: 500px;
}

    input:focus, textarea:focus {
        border: 1px solid #7ac0da;
    }

    input[type="checkbox"] {
        background: transparent;
        border: inherit;
        width: auto;
    }

    input[type="submit"],
    input[type="button"],
    button {
        background-color: #d3dce0;
        border: 1px solid #787878;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        font-weight: 600;
        padding: 7px;
        margin-right: 8px;
        width: auto;
    }

    td input[type="submit"],
    td input[type="button"],
    td button {
        font-size: 1em;
        padding: 4px;
        margin-right: 4px;
    }

/* info and errors */
.message-info {
    border: 1px solid;
    clear: both;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
.message-infolog {
    border: 1px solid;
    clear: both;
    padding: 3px 7px;
    color-rendering:optimizeQuality;
    border-color:#3e5667;
}

.message-error {
    clear: both;
    color: #e80c4d;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 20px 0 10px 0;
}

.message-success {
    color: #7ac0da;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 20px 0 10px 0;
}

.error {
    color: #e80c4d;
}

/* styles for validation helpers */
.field-validation-error {
    color: #e80c4d;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.field-validation-valid {
    display: none;
}

input.input-validation-error {
    border: 1px solid #e80c4d;
}

input[type="checkbox"].input-validation-error {
    border: 0 none;
}

.validation-summary-errors {
    color: #e80c4d;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

.validation-summary-valid {
    display: none;
}


/* tables
----------------------------------------------------------*/
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    margin-top: 0.75em;
    border: 0 none;
}

th {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    text-align: left;
    border: none 0px;
    padding-left: 0;
}

    th a {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
    }

    th a:link, th a:visited, th a:active, th a:hover {
        color: #333;
        font-weight: 600;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 0;
    }

    th a:hover {
        color: #000;
    }

    th.asc a, th.desc a {
        margin-right: .75em;
    }

    th.asc a:after, th.desc a:after {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0em;
        top: 0;
        font-size: 0.75em;
    }

    th.asc a:after {
        content: '▲';
    }

    th.desc a:after {
        content: '▼';
    }

td {
    padding: 0.25em 2em 0.25em 0em;
    border: 0 none;
}

tr.pager td {
    padding: 0 0.25em 0 0;
}


/********************
*   Mobile Styles   *
********************/
@media only screen and (max-width: 850px) {

    /* header
    ----------------------------------------------------------*/
    header .float-left,
    header .float-right {
        float: none;
    }

    /* logo */
    header .site-title {
        margin: 10px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    /* login */
    #login {
        font-size: .85em;
        margin: 0 0 12px;
        text-align: center;
    }

        #login ul {
            margin: 5px 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #login li {
            display: inline;
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #login a {
            background: none;
            color: #999;
            font-weight: 600;
            margin: 2px;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #login a:hover {
            color: #333;
        }

    /* menu */
    nav {
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }

    ul#menu {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: center;
    }

        ul#menu li {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }


    /* main layout
    ----------------------------------------------------------*/
    .main-content,
    .featured + .main-content {
        background-position: 10px 0;
    }

    .content-wrapper {
        padding-right: 10px;
        padding-left: 10px;
    }

    .featured .content-wrapper {
        padding: 10px;
    }

    /* page content */
    article, aside {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }

    /* ordered list */
    ol.round {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding-left: 0;
    }

        ol.round li {
            padding-left: 10px;
            margin: 25px 0;
        }

            ol.round li.zero,
            ol.round li.one,
            ol.round li.two,
            ol.round li.three,
            ol.round li.four,
            ol.round li.five,
            ol.round li.six,
            ol.round li.seven,
            ol.round li.eight,
            ol.round li.nine {
                background: none;
            }

     /* features */
     section.feature {
        float: none;
        padding: 10px;
        width: auto;
     }

        section.feature img {
            color: #999;
            content: attr(alt);
            font-size: 1.5em;
            font-weight: 600;
        }

    /* forms */
    input {
        width: 90%;
    }

    /* login page */
    #loginForm {
        border-right: none;
        float: none;
        width: auto;
    }

        #loginForm .validation-error {
            display: block;
            margin-left: 15px;
        }

    #socialLoginForm {
        margin-left: 0;
        float: none;
        width: auto;
    }


    /* footer
    ----------------------------------------------------------*/
    footer .float-left,
    footer .float-right {
        float: none;
    }

    footer {
        text-align: center;
        height: auto;
        padding: 10px 0;
    }

        footer p {
            margin: 0;
        }
}
```

**I will appreciate any help and Subjection! Thanks**

Comment: Make sure styles from template are not affecting your view.

Comment: @HasanAli The Style is not Affecting the Login Form. I checked that as well. Perhaps should I add the style to the question for you to see:

Comment: @HasanAli No luck, I have remove the style.css that I have but still nothing.

Comment: Share Just the HTML markup with CSS. Providing a fiddle will also help.

Comment: @Kumar_Vikas the HTML markup is already there. Instead lt me add the CSS as well

Comment: So you need the "OR" section to be below the email/password fields instead of to the right?

Comment: @StaticBeagle Yes, I need the Or Section to be Below  and Not to the Right. But I will appreciate it if the design of the login page may llok alike with the first template. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this problem sorted by reviewing all my Cascading Styles and All my JS on my web application.Then I found out that there were many conflited involved in the Login Divs and form tag ID and the rest of the form was not properly formated and the class were massed out.

> I gathered all the stylesheets and Layout to a new razor page that is were i finally got rid of the miss format form on the page. since I was using  BootStrap 3.3.7, My application was pointing to BootStrap 4.0.0. so By fixing the above misplacement, the page ran smoothly and same with the page in the application as well.

Great Thanks to all.